# Julian Schwinger videos, is there any?

Tags: soft-question, history

I googled in vain and found nothing. I am surprised. Maybe somebody knows about videos of Julian Schwinger available on Internet?

Comment: There is a 1960s BBC television show narrated by Schwinger. I have seen the associated book and pictures.

Comment: @ChangweiZhou: It's called "understanding space and time" and was produced by the BBC in 1979, as part of an "open university" series of programs.

Comment: I finally found one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NoUqqVISVmk  --  Schwinger speaks at about 6 mins, 17 mins, and 25 mins (roughly, that's from memory).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it focuses on a physicist rather than physics matters.